# How to pass data from React front end Hooks to Express backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I'm trying to pass data from my react front end which is set up using hooks to my node/express server.

Body content is coming up empty when i try to console log the request (userLog) in express back end. Could someone please help me out? Thanks!

Express NodeJS app.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true
  })
)

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app
  .route('/api/hello')
  .get((req, res) => {
    res.send('Express Server Online')
  })

  .post((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.userLog)
  })

app.listen(5000, function(err) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log('Express Server started successfully at Port 5000')
  }
})
```

React App.js front end

```js
import React from 'react'

function App() {
  const [userLog, setUserLog] = useState({
    register: false,
    login: false
  })

  function recordUser(event) {
    const eventName = event.target.name
    setUserLog(prevValue => {
      return { ...prevValue, [eventName]: true }
    })
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/hello', userLog).then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      console.log(res.data)
    })
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <a className="nav-link " onClick={recordUser} href="#" name="login">
        Login <span className="sr-only">(current)</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: did you ever try to do `console.log` in the express request handler to know if the ajax call from React Component reach the express API

Comment: Yes ...the post request is reaching the express node, (i logged this in console to verify), however the body of the request is blank.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a tag to execute a function this is not ideal you must put it in a button tag and you must prevent the default action before anything else. Also there is no respond from your POST => /api/hello route. You must return something in order to catch it.

```js
...
  function recordUser(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const eventName = event.target.name
    setUserLog(prevValue => {
      return { ...prevValue, [eventName]: true }
    })
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/hello', userLog).then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      console.log(res.data)
    })
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button className="nav-link " onClick={recordUser}>
        Login <span className="sr-only">(current)</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  )
....
```

I recommend doing this.